# Find area bounded by complex graph.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let $w=-\frac 12+i\frac {√3}{2}$ and $S$ denote the set of all the complex numbers in the argand plane of the form $a+bw+cw^2$,  where $a,b$ and $c$ belong to $[0,1]$.

Then find the area and perimeter traced by $S$.

Please give approach to find answer.

Comment: Edit the question to include your efforts. Mere problem statements are not answered on this forum.

Comment: Which makes this a gadheda platform.